# Why won't my Ubuntu recognize 15.04?

Tags: updates, 15.04, do-release-upgrade

so i type `do-release-upgrade -d` and I get this:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

and I've tried upgrading the software in every way, it claims my version is up to date. I feel that upgrading is the only solution to stopping these computer crashes.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you have now?

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 easily now.

Fist make sure all updates are applied to your current system "sudo apt-get upgrade"

Then make sure the

```
file /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

has the line:

```
Prompt=normal
```

Then the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: says "no new release found"...isn't that bizzar? im trying to figure out which mechanism is malfunctioning...but i guess ill never know

Comment: Your prompts were normal?

Comment: I would check in your settings menu and select any new release then run the software updater.

Comment: this worked for me when I set `Prompt=normal`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ubuntu is configured to notify you about any new versions available, not just about 'long-term support' versions.

Go to 'Software & Updates' and check if the Updates tab is configured as the image shows:

[image: Software Updates config]

With such a config it should detect that 15.04 is already available and should prompt you to install it.